# mediaCodec flush doesn't return

Tags: android, android-mediacodec

I'm decoding a video with Android, and apply some treatment to the audio part before to display it. To be sure both streams are synchronised, I'm using the MediaSync object.
When I receive a BUFFER_FLAG_END_OF_STREAM flag, I want to loop my video. I have a "seekTo" function to do that (I call it with msec = 0, of course):

```
       public void seekTo(int msec) throws IllegalStateException {
        boolean restart = true;
        if (isPause) {
            restart = false;
        }
        isPause = true;
        mediaSync.setPlaybackParams(new PlaybackParams().setSpeed(0.f));

        synchronized (mVideoLock) {
            if (mVideoExtractor != null) {
                Log.d(TAG, "Loop video");
                mVideoExtractor.seekTo(msec * 1000, SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
                mVideoDecoder.flush();
            }
        }
        synchronized (mAudioLock) {
            if (mAudioExtractor != null) {
                mAudioExtractor.seekTo(msec * 1000, SEEK_TO_CLOSEST_SYNC);
                mAudioDecoder.flush();

                mAudioTrack.pause();
                mAudioTrack.flush();
                mAudioTrack.setPlaybackHeadPosition(0);
                mAudioTrack.play();
            }
        }

    mediaSync.setPlaybackParams(new PlaybackParams().setSpeed(1.f));
    if (restart) {
        isPause = false;
    }
```

if 'isPause' is true, I don't make any action when onOutputBufferAvailable(...) is called.

My problem is that I never come back from the "mVideoDecoder.flush()" call. So my video stopped.
Any hint ? :)